# Portability concern

Tags: c, struct, portability

I have written a program that does all sorts of processing and write/reads the results in a file.

This "result" is in a struct like this

```
struct res
{
    char  id;
    char* values;
    int   count; 
    long  samplenumber;
};
```

and let's say I write/ read with functions like these

```
write( file, &result, sizeof(struct res) );
read(file, &result, filesize(file) );
```

My concern is : What could go wrong if the struct is written on a 32b machine and read on a 64 (and other way around) ?

I'm not asking for any improvements of what I'm currently doing, but just about the issues with the way things work in terms of portability.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I'm using C.

Comment: Define everything with a size: i.e., `unsigned char`, `uint32_t` (or `int32_t`), and consider changing the `long`, because that varies; you may want `uint64_t`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 problems here:

**~** Sizes of types can be different. (Use types from `stdint.h` like `uint32_t`.)

**~** Compiler usually will insert padding into your struct, like

```
struct res
{
    char  id;
    /* unused byte */
    /* unused byte */
    /* unused byte */
    char* values;
    int   count; 
    long  samplenumber;
};
```

**~** Endianness of integers can be different. For example, `3555896322` can be represented as
`D3 F2 AC 02` or `02 AC F2 D3`.

**~** `char*` will be saved to file as useless pointer. You need to write string yourself, byte by byte.

**Solution:**

**~** Use types from `stdint.h`.

**~** Don't use structs for saving. (Or use so called `#pragma pack`, but keep in mind that it's not portable.)

**~** Write integers byte by byte, like

```
uint32_t var = 3555896322;
putc(var >>  0 & 0xff, file);
putc(var >>  8 & 0xff, file);
putc(var >> 16 & 0xff, file);
putc(var >> 24 & 0xff, file);
```

**~** Write strings byte by byte, for example:

```
const char *ptr = "Hello, young programmer!";
while (*ptr)
    putc(*(ptr++), file);
putc('\0', file);
```

**~** Floating-point types can be saved directly, they usually have same size everywhere:

```
float a = 1.23;
fwrite(&a, sizeof (float), 1, file);
```

Comment: > Don't use structs for saving.
You should mention that there is feature called "packing" that allow to avoid that. `#pragma pack` in VC or `__attribute__((packed))` does the thing.

Comment: @user300234 Of course they can, but AFAIK it's very rare case.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, everything will go wrong because sizes of types are different on platforms.

First of all replace types with ones from `stdint.h`

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct res
{
    uint8_t   id;
    char*     values;
    uint32_t  count; 
    uint32_t  samplenumber;
};
```

Your also shouldn't write string as `char*`. When you read it again you just get stale pointer. Use string of predefined size:

```
 char values[256];
```

Or write string manually in a separate write call.

Comment: This is still not necessarily portable, because the size of padding between members might change. And some platforms have different binary representation (big endian vs little endian, etc.)